# How to change Django model from class using boolean

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the location class in my models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    orderplaced = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ordersent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class locationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ["orderplaced", "order_sent_time"]

admin.site.register(Location, locationAdmin)
```

How do I make it so that the boolean ordersent controls the if order_sent_time is blank or not

[image]

I tried using

```
if ordersent:
    order_sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
else:
    order_sent_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

How can I get the boolean to affect order_sent_time?

Comment: Can you explain more further this sentence : *How do I make it so that the boolean ordersent controls the if order_sent_time is blank or not*

Comment: If the boolean ordersent is set to True, then order_sent_time will get the current date and time. If ordersent is False, then order_sent_time will be not get the current date and time. Is what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To dynamically set some value of an object in Django, you can override the save() method :**

```
# Assume that (USE_TZ=True) in settings file
from django.utils import timezone

class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    orderplaced = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    ordersent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    order_sent_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If ordersent is True then set order_sent_time to now
        if ordersent:
            self.order_sent_time = timezone.now()
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 
        return self
```

*Note :* Each time you will create or edit a Location object, it will check if the `ordersent` variable is True, then `order_sent_time` will be set to the runtime date. Else it's will be none.